# Vertex positions from particle position

Tags: geometry, interpolation, simulation, particles

I have a question about Nvidia Flex or any particle based simulation in general:

The particles are created by sampling the mesh, which can result in fewer particles than there are vertices in the mesh.

After computing the new particle positions, how are the vertex positions updated based on the particle positions?

Are they simply projected onto a point within the particle?
And is the mesh fully updated or is it just rendered in a modified way?

Sorry for these unprofessional questions.
I appreciate any help.